# Update 1 record in a column with calculations

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using MS access for a work project

I've got a table with figure 1 and figure 2
figure 1 is prepopulated but figure 2 is entered using the ".edit" function.

i can get the edit function to work but i need figure 1 and figure 2 added together and inserted into figure 3 column.

At the moment if have:

```
Set dbLogUpdate = CurrentDb
Set LogRecUpdate = dbLogUpdate.OpenRecordset("tblData")

LogRecUpdate.Edit
LogRecUpdate("Figure 2").Value = [Figure 2].Value
LogRecUpdate.Update
```

when figure 2 is typed in i need the record for figure 3 updated to show the results of the calculation.

Comment: How are you inputting the data? In a bound form this should be pretty easy. Also, when you say added together, do you mean mathematically, or concatenated? E.g. should 1 and 2 equal 3 or 12?

Comment: Can you just change figure 3 to be a calculated field?
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx

Comment: If the above is all of your code, then I think you have a bigger problem - where/how are you getting to the desired record to update? Unless your table has only one row, that code will always update the first row. And as @BFDatabaseAdmin noted, if 'Figure 2' is bound to the form, then it will get updated without any action on your part. IF the above is true, then is Figure 3 bound / unbound / not present on the form? Add an 'On Change' event for Figure 2 and set the value for Figure 3 there - DEPENDING on more info....